# Add new disk as sublv to LVM2 raid5 & create rmeta and rimage

Tags: partitioning, lvm, raid5

When I do a `lsblk`, I get the following:

```
sdc                             8:32   0   9.1T  0 disk
├─data-data_rmeta_2           253:6    0     4M  0 lvm
│ └─data-data                 253:8    0  18.2T  0 lvm   /mnt/sdc
└─data-data_rimage_2          253:7    0   9.1T  0 lvm
  └─data-data                 253:8    0  18.2T  0 lvm   /mnt/sdc
sdd                             8:48   0   9.1T  0 disk
├─data-data_rmeta_1           253:4    0     4M  0 lvm
│ └─data-data                 253:8    0  18.2T  0 lvm   /mnt/sdc
└─data-data_rimage_1          253:5    0   9.1T  0 lvm
  └─data-data                 253:8    0  18.2T  0 lvm   /mnt/sdc
sde                             8:64   0   9.1T  0 disk
├─data-data_rmeta_0           253:2    0     4M  0 lvm
│ └─data-data                 253:8    0  18.2T  0 lvm   /mnt/sdc
└─data-data_rimage_0          253:3    0   9.1T  0 lvm
  └─data-data                 253:8    0  18.2T  0 lvm   /mnt/sdc
sdf                             8:80   0   9.1T  0 disk
```

I cannot seem to extend my LV by /dev/sdf.

When I do a `lvextend -0r -l +100%FREE /dev/data/data`, the system responds with

```
  Using stripesize of last segment 64.00 KiB
  Size of logical volume data/data unchanged from 18.19 TiB (4768764 extents).
  Logical volume data/data successfully resized.
```

The LV should be 27.29 as evidenced by `vgdisplay data`

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               data
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        4
  Metadata Sequence No  34
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                4
  Act PV                4
  VG Size               36.38 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              9537532
  Alloc PE / Size       7153149 / <27.29 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       2384383 / <9.10 TiB
  VG UUID               4eex8c-TZo3-P7N0-pp8m-jQ9c-uTf2-lZe1XN
```

What can I do? I think Google is now tired from all the searches I've done on this matter. Can ***ANYONE*** help me??

TIA

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Per `lsb_release -a`

`Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal`